# Trigger:Too many soql query error

Tags: trigger, soql, insert

when I create or update record, am getting too many soql query error. following are my code:

```java
trigger UpdateAssetImageurl on SymphonyIPM__Patent__c (after insert,after update) {

    List<SymphonyIPM__Patent__c> objPatents = [SELECT Id,  SymphonyIPM__Asset_Image__c, Asset_Image_Url__c FROM SymphonyIPM__Patent__c where id IN: Trigger.new];
    for(SymphonyIPM__Patent__c objPatent : objPatents)
    {
        if (objPatent.SymphonyIPM__Asset_Image__c!=null)
        {
            objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.SymphonyIPM__Asset_Image__c;
            system.debug(objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c);
            objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('<img src="','');
            objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('" width="500" height="281"></img>','');
            objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('&amp;','&');
            objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('seq=1&IsImage=1','');
            system.debug(objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c);    
        }

    }
    update objPatents;
}
```

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: i am getting this error :CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, UpdateAssetImageurl: maximum trigger depth exceeded Patent trigger event AfterInsert Patent trigger event AfterUpdate

Comment: if you have anything to add, please **[edit]** your post rather than followin up on comments, thanks

Comment: You have a trigger that runs when `SymphonyIPM__Patent__c` instances are _updated_ and then within that trigger you are _updating_ `SymphonyIPM__Patent__c` instances. So you enter an infinite loop. See Tushar's answer that avoids that.

Comment: The error that your question states that you're receiving is different from the error that you provided us in the comments. Please clarify which one you are actually seeing (again, you should do this as an [edit] to your question, not as a comment on your question). Also, paraphrasing error messages does not help people understand your problem. Error messages are generally one of the things that you should provide **verbatim** (i.e. word-for-word) along with the stack trace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a Query here.  You can easily do this in Before insert and Before update event.

```
trigger UpdateAssetImageurl on SymphonyIPM__Patent__c (before insert,before update) {

 for(SymphonyIPM__Patent__c objPatent : Trigger.New)
{
    if (objPatent.SymphonyIPM__Asset_Image__c!=null)
    {
        objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.SymphonyIPM__Asset_Image__c;
        system.debug(objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c);
        objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('<img src="','');
        objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('" width="500" height="281"></img>','');
        objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('&amp;','&');
        objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c = objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c.replace('seq=1&IsImage=1','');
        system.debug(objPatent.Asset_Image_Url__c);    
    }

}

}
```

In before trigger we also don't need DML.